# How to delete observations based on changes in specific variable?

Tags: r, formatting, panel, data-cleaning, rowdeleting

I have a balanced panel data table containing thousands of firms with observations in two years each (1 & 2). For the data cleaning process I need to exclude observations where there is a shift between the years in a supposedly time-constant variable.

```
example <- matrix(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0), ncol=3)
colnames(example) <- c('id', 'year', 'supposedly time-constant')
example.table <- data.table(example)
example.table

   id year supposedly time-constant
1:  1    1                        1
2:  1    2                        1
3:  2    1                        0
4:  2    2                        0
5:  3    1                        0
6:  3    2                        1
7:  4    1                        1
8:  4    2                        0
```

So, in the above table, firms 3 & 4 both show a change in the supposedly time-constant variable, so they would need to be removed. Firms 1 & 2 are what I wish to have. I need a code/function that allows me to clean my data.

I seem to have reached the limits of my R knowledge and hope I can find help here - thanks in advance!

Comment: What changes do firms 3 and 4 have? Should they always be 1s or all 0s?

Comment: It is just about that there is a change between the years, either 0 to 1 or 1 to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` and select groups which have only one unique value

```
library(dplyr)
example.table %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(`supposedly time-constant`) == 1)


#     id  year `supposedly time-constant`
#  <dbl> <dbl>                      <dbl>
#1     1     1                          1
#2     1     2                          1
#3     2     1                          0
#4     2     2                          0
```

---

Same logic in base R using `ave` would be

```
example.table[with(example.table, ave(`supposedly time-constant`, id, 
             FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1), ]
```

Comment: Removed my comment after seeing your edit. Although I think it was a good option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use data.table and chaining concept to identify which ID's/firms show such a change:

```
example.table[, .(unq_val = length(unique(`supposedly time-constant`))), by = .(id)][unq_val >= 2, .(id)]
```

The above line of code can be broken down as follows:
1. For each id (in the 'by'argument), 
2. Create a variable called unq_val which counts the total unique `supposedly time-constant',
3. Then selects only firms/id's which contain value >= 2 for such a variable.

The output of the code is:

```
   id
1:  3
2:  4
```

Which is a data.table, which you can then use to filter out observations from your original data.

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` approach with `all` which selects all groups that have all 0s or all 1s. This will be inefficient if you have so many supposedly time-constant conditions:

```
    library(dplyr)
    example.table %>% 
       group_by(id) %>% 
       filter(all(`supposedly time-constant`==1) | all(`supposedly time-constant`==0))
    # A tibble: 4 x 3
    # Groups:   id [2]
         id  year `supposedly time-constant`
      <dbl> <dbl>                      <dbl>
    1     1     1                          1
    2     1     2                          1
    3     2     1                          0
    4     2     2                          0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` methods as it is a `data.table`.  Grouped by 'id', check the length of unique elemnts in `supposedly time-constant` is equal to 1 and subset the `.SD` (Subset of data.table)

```
library(data.table)
example.table[, .SD[uniqueN(`supposedly time-constant`) == 1], by = id]
#     id year supposedly time-constant
#1:  1    1                        1
#2:  1    2                        1
#3:  2    1                        0
#4:  2    2                        0
```

---

Or a bit faster option would be `.I`

```
example.table[example.table[, .I[uniqueN(`supposedly time-constant`)
            == 1], by = id]$V1]
#   id year supposedly time-constant
#1:  1    1                        1
#2:  1    2                        1
#3:  2    1                        0
#4:  2    2                        0
```